# Ubuntu shutting down arbitrarily when charger not connected despite sufficient battery

Tags: gnome, 18.04, suspend, shutdown, battery

Ubuntu 18.04 arbitrarily turns off when charger is not connected to my Asus UX305 ZenBook Laptop, even though there's a good charge on the battery.

Also, Ubuntu does not wake even on pressing the power key until I connect the charger, otherwise **it shows the company logo for a moment and shuts down again** without going to the gnome login screen.

Another strange thing that when I connect the charger and start the system it **shows the company logo twice or thrice** and then after logging to the system **the date and time of system get set to *Satuday 19:03*** . For reference I installed ubuntu on *Saturday Morning*, and the time *Satuday 19:03* does not seem anything special (I might have downloaded some package maybe)

This has been happening since yesterday, and it not really a battery issue also I guess since laptop was 33% charged the last time it happened.

Specs :

- Asus UX305 ZenBook Laptop
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with gnome desktop enviornment
- Not dual boot, only ubuntu is present

Was using Gnome on a different Linux kernel earlier and all worked OK.

Update 1:
[Image of dkpg.log with time near Saturday 19:03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hIIY.png), not sure if it helps, and nothin seems wrong with packages as well.

Update 2:
It turned off again, the battery was again about 33% after it turned on like the last time. Is it likely to be battery issue???

According to ubuntu power statistics tool :
Energy when Full : 39.9 Wh
Energy (design) : 56 Wh

Comment: Does this occur when you boot and run from a LiveUSB of Ubuntu 18.04 ? Does it occur with a LiveUSB of Xubuntu 18.04?

Comment: It has been pretty arbitrary, it occured last time half an hour ago. I disconnected charger after I started and laptop has survived till now. Not sure if I can capture it on liveUSB!!

Comment: have you tried to disable all suspend/hibernation/poweroff options ?

Comment: No, didnt seem like a suspend problem as I was typing when it suddenly went off! Turned off the suspend now though..

Comment: Probably a hardware problem, loose battery contacts? Try make sure the contact are all clean, and spring contact have tentions.

Comment: Yeahh got shut down 4 times at the 33% mark